# Can Vagrant Package Multiple VMs?

Tags: vagrant

I have a four-server Vagrant virtual machine environment which takes significant time to destroy and rebuild.  What I'd like to be able to do is package these four VMs from one Vagrantfile.  This [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/69) was raised in 2010 and then closed without explanation in 2012.  The Vagrant [Package](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/package.html) doc doesn't discuss this option.  Has anyone know whether or not this can be done?